# Stop background repeating with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-animations

I have a set a `<li>` to my background and added keyframes to cycle through the images. My goal is to use these to create a lean looped animation, but I can't stop the background image from repeating.

There is one image that I cant control, while the one beneath is sized and positioned correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.cb-slideshow span { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 8s linear infinite 0s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
  animation-delay: 1s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
  animation-delay: 2s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
  animation-delay: 3s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
  animation-delay: 4s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
  animation-delay: 5s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/7.jpg);
  animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) span { 
  background-image: url(../images/8.jpg);
  animation-delay: 7s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
  0% { opacity: 0 }
  0.1% { opacity: 1 } 
  12.5% { opacity: 1 }
  12.6% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/1.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/2.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/3.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/4.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/5.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/6.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/7.jpg" ></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><img src="Images/8.jpg" ></span>
    </li>                                  
</ul>
```

Comment: ***** I have set a 'list item' *****

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to prevent the image from repeating.

Comment: Thanks Skully, but as you can see from my code - it's already being included and is still repeating.

Comment: Have you tried placing it within the same class? You have it within `.cb-slideshow span`.

Comment: I think it's because the `<li>` is set as the background image, yet is not recognised as such.

Comment: What about placing it inline then? `background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) no-repeat;`

Comment: That worked to a degree, but now it's non-responsive.
I'll have a fiddle with it and get back if I can't work it out.

Comment: Nah using inline causes the image underneath (the one I want) to disappear and keeps the crappy static one I want removed.

Comment: Sounds weird as shorthand or full syntax should be dead on equal... but if using shorthand it’s just `background`, not `background-image`.

Comment: I solved it.

Turns out I was adding the image twice - once in the span using html and then again using CSS.
I deleted it from the html and now the image cycles like a dream.

Thanks for your help mate.